# Emacs autoindent indenting way too deep

Tags: emacs, auto-indent

I've a before-save hook for autoindenting files. Emacs is inserting TONS of extra indentation, how can I fix this? This problem is particularly offensive for filetypes with significant whitespace (Python, Mardown, Stylus).

https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs

**Update**: Specifically, `(indent-region (point-min) (point-max))` is improperly indenting my code, verified by manually applying `M-: (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))`.

Comment: You have accidentally forgotten to provide a single example of the problem. (Personally I think automatically re-indenting the entire file upon saving is an awful idea, btw; but presumably the actual issue here is not dependent on *when* you're doing the indenting.)

Comment: Can you add a minimal sample-file that gets indented wrong? Using the linked .emacs I wasn't able to reproduce the error. BTW: `(setq tab-width 2)` line 70 in your init file is useless as it is a buffer local variable. You have to use `(setq-default tab-width 2)` instead.

Comment: Yep. https://gist.github.com/mcandre/5093435